# PHP sort array of arrays with key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as shown below. I want to sort it with the **srp** value in ascending order. How can I do this in PHP. I am a beginner I think it can be done using **usort()** but am not sure how to do it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1900
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1000
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4
            [title] => JIVI X525(Red)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1250
        )

)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4
            [title] => JIVI X525(Red)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1250
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver)
            [mrp] => 0
            [srp] => 1900
        )
)
```

My Class looks like this:

> ```
> class TopDealsDAOMongoImpl implements TopDealsDAO{
>     //put your code here
>     public function getTopDeals() {
>         $topDeals = json_decode(json_encode(MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::select("product_id","affiliate_id","title","our_product_id","mrp","srp","product_url","category_name","ID")->where('top_deal','true')->get()));
>         function my_sort($a,$b)
>         {
>             if ($a->srp == $b->srp) return 0;
>             return ($a->srp < $b->srp)?-1:1;
>         }
>
>         uasort($topDeals, 'my_sort'); 
>
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: That answers provided there produces Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Before posting a question on SO.  Try to self solve and research.  When you post a duplicate question, you create site bloat and waste the time of volunteers.

Comment: Research more/other questions on SO.  This a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using usort in php to sort an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286597/using-usort-in-php-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @Dexter see my answer below for your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code,
I hope it is helpful.

> PHP Script.

```
<?php
    // Static array.
    $array=array();
    $array[0]=array(
        '_id'=>'5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3',
        'title'=>'Zen M4S(Silver) 1',
        'srp'=>1900
    );
    $array[1]=array(
        '_id'=>'5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2',
        'title'=>'Zen M4S(Silver) 2',
        'srp'=>1000
    );
    $array[2]=array(
        '_id'=>'5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4',
        'title'=>'Zen M4S(Silver) 1',
        'srp'=>1250
    );

    // For acending sorting.
    function asc_sort_json($array1,$array2){
        $on = 'srp';
        if ($array1[$on] == $array2[$on]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($array1[$on] < $array2[$on]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // For decending sorting.
    function desc_sort_json($array1,$array2){
        $on = 'srp';
        if ($array1[$on] == $array2[$on]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($array1[$on] < $array2[$on]) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    $array_json = json_encode($array); // encode array in json
    $array_json1 = json_decode($array_json); // decode json from array because get json object
    $array_json2 = json_decode(json_encode($array_json1),true); // parse json into array

    usort($array_json2, "asc_sort_json"); // Call function for acending order.
    $array_json2 = json_decode(json_encode($array_json2)); // Array to json.

    $array_json1 = json_encode($array); // encode array in json
    $array_json2 = json_decode($array_json1); // decode json from array because get json object
    $array_json3 = json_decode(json_encode($array_json2),true); // parse json into array

    usort($array_json3, "desc_sort_json"); // Call function for decending order.
    $array_json4 = json_decode(json_encode($array_json2)); // Array to json.
?>
```

> Outputs.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_json2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_json4);

// Asc 
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 2
            [srp] => 1000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 1
            [srp] => 1250
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 1
            [srp] => 1900
        )

)

// Desc
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 2
            [srp] => 1000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 1
            [srp] => 1250
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3
            [title] => Zen M4S(Silver) 1
            [srp] => 1900
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
// Sort array
uasort($array, 'cmp');

function cmp($a, $b) {
   if ($a['srp'] == $b['srp']) {
      return 0;
   }
   // Return in acsending order
   return ($a['srp'] < $b['srp']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Read more: [Uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: [ErrorException]                                                                                            
  uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'my_sort' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Can you post the code that returned that error here? my_sort was not in my example.

Comment: also tried yours:
uasort($topDeals, 'cmp');
        var_dump($topDeals);
        function cmp($a, $b) {
           if ($a['srp'] == $b['srp']) {
              return 0;
           }
           // Return in acsending order
           return ($a['srp'] < $b['srp']) ? -1 : 1;
        }

Comment: Okay you want the answer [Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Answer (score 0):

For simple array

```
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
    if ($a['srp'] == $b['srp']) return 0;
    return ($a['srp'] < $b['srp'])?-1:1;
}

uasort($array, 'my_sort'); // replace $array with your variable
```

For StdObject syntax will be:

```
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
    if ($a->srp == $b->srp) return 0;
    return ($a->srp < $b->srp)?-1:1;
}

uasort($array, 'my_sort'); // replace $array with your variable
```

Comment: [ErrorException]                                                                                            
  uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'my_sort' not found or invalid function name

Comment: have you added my_sort function and also changed name of `$array` to your array name?

Comment: then you should have a look on this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228477/php-usort-expects-parameter-2-to-be-a-valid-callback-not-in-a-class

Comment: also check how to call function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725165/calling-a-function-within-a-class-method

Answer (score -1):

use `usort` and pass user define function in it.

```
$tmp =  new stdClass;
$tmp->_id="5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3";
$tmp->title="Zen M4S(Silver)";
$tmp->mrp=0;
$tmp->srp=1900;

$tmp1 =  new stdClass;
$tmp1->_id="5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2";
$tmp1->title="Zen M4S(Silver)";
$tmp1->mrp=0;
$tmp1->srp=1000;

$tmp2 =  new stdClass;
$tmp2->_id="5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4";
$tmp2->title="JIVI X525(Red)";
$tmp2->mrp=0;
$tmp2->srp=1250;

$new_array = array($tmp,$tmp1,$tmp2);
function sort_arr($a, $b)
{
    return ($a->srp<$b->srp)?-1:1;
}

usort($new_array, "sort_arr");
var_dump($new_array);
```

**From your edit you are using class, So you can do it like this:**

```
class TopDealsDAOMongoImpl implements TopDealsDAO{
    //put your code here
    public function getTopDeals() {
        $topDeals = json_decode(json_encode(MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::select("product_id","affiliate_id","title","our_product_id","mrp","srp","product_url","category_name","ID")->where('top_deal','true')->get()));


        uasort($topDeals, array($this, "sort_arr")); 

    }
    public function sort_arr($a,$b)
    {
        if ($a->srp == $b->srp) return 0;
        return ($a->srp < $b->srp)?-1:1;
    }


}
```

o/p:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public '_id' => string '5911af8209ed4456d069b1d2' (length=24)
      public 'title' => string 'Zen M4S(Silver)' (length=15)
      public 'mrp' => int 0
      public 'srp' => int 1000
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public '_id' => string '5911af8209ed4456d069b1d4' (length=24)
      public 'title' => string 'JIVI X525(Red)' (length=14)
      public 'mrp' => int 0
      public 'srp' => int 1250
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public '_id' => string '5911af8209ed4456d069b1d3' (length=24)
      public 'title' => string 'Zen M4S(Silver)' (length=15)
      public 'mrp' => int 0
      public 'srp' => int 1900
```

Comment: [ErrorException]                         
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It must be diffrent thing. In this q/a there is no `foreach` loop

Comment: usort($topDeals, function($a, $b) { return $b->srp - $a->srp; });
        var_dump($topDeals);
this worked